# Does NETWORK_PROVIDER work with only 3G enabled

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I need to get the users location (say at a restaurant). The user has his phone/device which is connected to the internet using 3G (wifi is turned on but no internet is available since the restaurant doesnt provide free wifi). The device may or may not have a sim card (if its a phone sim card is present, but if its a tablet like galaxy tab with 3G then only 3G is available).

I am thinking of using the `NETWORK_PROVIDER`. It seems to work perfectly with wifi, but I was wondering if it would work with only 3G. I do not completely understand how `NETWORK_PROVIDER` works. It uses the wifi hotspots or cellular triangulation, so I assume it MUST be connected to that wifi? In a restaurant he might have near by wifi but not connected to it, so I can only rely upon 3G.

The code I have used at the moment

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Will the provide me accurate location with 3G?

**EDIT**: What is the estimated accuracy of `NETWORK_PROVIDER`?

Comment: NETWORK_PROVIDER works with any kind of wireless network. Internet is not necessary. Only the phone should be connected to the network.

Comment: @TommasoResti What do you mean? Could you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From Android Developer Offical Reference:**

> **public static final String NETWORK_PROVIDER**
>   Added in API level 1
>   Name of the network location provider.
>   This provider determines location based on availability of **cell tower and WiFi** access points. Results are retrieved by means of a network lookup.
>   Constant Value: "network"

So 3G and WiFi both!

**SORRY, i misunderstood**

**Anyway**, you don't need to be connected to the wifi access point, the phone just need to FEEL the MAC address of the access point over the air! ;)

Have a look here -> http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/04/22/google_streetview_logs_wlans/
google is stealing our soul! GHGHGH

Comment: oh so it just needs to FEEL the wifi. That solves so many of my problems.